# Best way to test my LDAP password on servers that otherwise use SSH keys

Tags: ssh, unix, ldap

I work in an environment where I cannot reset my own LDAP password. I have to open a ticket with the NOC and they reset it for me. That's fine, except that sometimes they don't actually reset my LDAP password, but some other thing that starts with an 'L'... so I like to test to confirm every time they reset it for me.

Anyway - I use ssh keys between all of the servers I generally do work on and thus don't normally need to supply a password. So, short of altering one of my ~/.ssh/authorized_keys files, is there a simple way for me to test that my new LDAP password actually is what i think it is? Sort of like a `whoami` that prompts for password?

Comment: If your servers are LDAP integrated for user authentication and allow the use of password for login then just use ssh options like this `ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no` This will enforce password usage for the ssh connection.

Comment: @Zina please, submit it as an answer, since it is completely answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to test ssh access to a server in your environment which is LDAP integrated for user authentication and allows the use of password for login.

If this is the case, you can test the validity of your password by issuing the ssh command with options for preferring password authentication over public key and not to use public key authentication at all.

This is done like this:

`ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no <your_username>@<ldap_integrated_host>`

Where options used:

- `PreferredAuthentications=password` - use password authentication
- `PubkeyAuthentication=no` - do NOT use public key authentication

You can read more about options in the `man ssh_config` pages as noted in `man ssh`.